# Increase paragraph in \moderncvstyle{classic}

Tags: paragraphs

I want to slightly increase the space between paragraphs in this cover letter:

```
%% start of file `template.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2013 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}      
\moderncvstyle{classic}                   

\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} 
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}     
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makelettertitle}% <cmd>
 {\raggedright \@opening}% <search>
 {\@opening}% <replace>
 {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\moderncvcolor{green}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\address{X}{Y}{Z}
\phone[mobile]{+00~(000)~0000~0000} 
\email{mail}  
\homepage{www.infectionmetal.com}  

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
% recipient data
\recipient{Lee MacBride\\News Editor}{27 Hoxton Street\\London N1 6NH\\UK}
\date{May 10, 2014}
\opening{Dear Lee,}
\closing{Sincerely,}
\enclosure[Attached]{one-sheet, demo album, reviews.} 
\makelettertitle

Mauris sit amet hendrerit erat. Aliquam at ullamcorper purus. Maecenas rutrum luctus felis vel dignissim. Pellentesque ut feugiat justo. Nam adipiscing eros pretium mi consectetur auctor. Ut vel quam sollicitudin, auctor lacus nec, venenatis mi. Maecenas consectetur fringilla lectus sit amet cursus.


Mauris sit amet hendrerit erat. Aliquam at ullamcorper purus. Maecenas rutrum luctus felis vel dignissim. Pellentesque ut feugiat justo. Nam adipiscing eros pretium mi consectetur auctor. Ut vel quam sollicitudin, auctor lacus nec, venenatis mi. Maecenas consectetur fringilla lectus sit amet cursus.


\makeletterclosing

\end{document}


%% end of file `template.tex'.
```

Just wondering, is it possible to add a position after the signature (e.g.: CEO, Manager)?

Is it possible to add an extra space between the end of the document and the signature. Since I need to stamp manually my signature on the printed document, the space is not enough to do so (my signature is kinda vertical.)

Comment: It doesn't work. I wrote "\parskip=12pt" but nothing happened.

Comment: I need to separate paragraphs as well as the sender information (upper right corner) from the date (May 10, 2014). I think it is too close at this very moment.

Comment: Unfortunately, LaTeX didn't compile when I introduce that line of code. I thought this was going to be an easy one. Damn LaTeX, how come is so complicated to add extra space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three issues.

1. One way to at a 'job title' to the closing would be the following (put the redefinition in between the `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` pair already in the example file:

   ```
   \renewcommand*{\makeletterclosing}{ 
     \@closing\\[3em]% 
     {\bfseries \@firstname~\@familyname}% 
     \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@jobtitle}}{}{\\\@jobtitle}% <-- added to orig. def
     \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@enclosure}}{}{%
       \\% 
       \vfill% 
       {\color{color2}\itshape\enclname: \@enclosure}}}

   \def\jobtitle#1{\def\@jobtitle{#1}}
   ```

   Then, when you want to include a 'job title' after the signiture, you'd add a

   ```
   \jobtitle{Manager \& CEO}
   ```
2. Regarding the `\parskip`, `moderncv` and the associated files redefine the length periodically.  The easiest (and least LaTeX-y) way to force your own length is to add a `\parskip=10pt` (etc.) after `\makelettertitle`; if you don't want the length to spread in a difficult to trace way, sandwich the new length between a `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` pair.
3. In order to increase the spacing between sender information block and the date, we can use `\patchcmd` (again):

   ```
   \patchcmd{\makelettertitle}%
     {\end{minipage}\\[1em]}%
     {\end{minipage}\\[2em]}%
     {}{}
   ```

So ... to put it all together in a single example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}

\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makelettertitle}% <cmd>
 {\raggedright \@opening}% <search>
 {\@opening}% <replace>
 {}{}% <success><failure>
\patchcmd{\makelettertitle}% <-- add space before date
  {\end{minipage}\\[1em]}%
  {\end{minipage}\\[2em]}% (change length as needed)
  {}{}
\renewcommand*{\makeletterclosing}{% <-- add an optional \jobtitle description
  \@closing\\[3em]%
  {\bfseries \@firstname~\@familyname}%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@jobtitle}}{}{\\\@jobtitle}%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@enclosure}}{}{%
    \\%
    \vfill%
    {\color{color2}\itshape\enclname: \@enclosure}}}
\def\jobtitle#1{\def\@jobtitle{#1}}
\makeatother

\moderncvcolor{green}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\parskip 20pt

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\jobtitle{CEO \& Manager}% <-- this is new, but not mandatory
\address{X}{Y}{Z}
\phone[mobile]{+00~(000)~0000~0000}
\email{mail}
\homepage{www.infectionmetal.com}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
% recipient data
\recipient{Lee MacBride\\News Editor}{27 Hoxton Street\\London N1 6NH\\UK}
\date{May 10, 2014}
\opening{Dear Lee,}
\closing{Sincerely,}
\enclosure[Attached]{one-sheet, demo album, reviews.}
\makelettertitle

\begingroup%  <-- here we are *locally* changing the value for \parskip
\parskip 12pt
Mauris sit amet hendrerit erat. Aliquam at ullamcorper purus. Maecenas rutrum luctus felis vel dignissim. Pellentesque ut feugiat justo. Nam adipiscing eros pretium mi consectetur auctor. Ut vel quam sollicitudin, auctor lacus nec, venenatis mi. Maecenas consectetur fringilla lectus sit amet cursus.


Mauris sit amet hendrerit erat. Aliquam at ullamcorper purus. Maecenas rutrum luctus felis vel dignissim. Pellentesque ut feugiat justo. Nam adipiscing eros pretium mi consectetur auctor. Ut vel quam sollicitudin, auctor lacus nec, venenatis mi. Maecenas consectetur fringilla lectus sit amet cursus.

\the\parskip % <-- let's test the value
\endgroup

\makeletterclosing

\the\parskip % <-- let's test the value again

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was really useful. My document looks great. Jus a little thing more, is it possible to add an extra space between the end of the document and the signature. Since I need to stamp manually my signature on the printed document, the space is not enough to do so (my signature is kinda vertical.)